Using default value in @Value annotation through a map
i want to use a static final map<String,String> to map a string against the default value in @Value annotation , like:
@Value("${property1:"+ map.get(property1)+"}")
private String prop1;

But java doesnt allow using dynamic values in annotation.
If i replace map with simply a variable say, String a="propert1value" and place this like:
@Value("${property1:"+ a+"}")
private String prop1;

It works now.
I have many property1, property2 ... variables so i want to use a map instead of individual variables for holding default values.
Any solutions?
I do not know how to approach this now.

Sounds like an XY problem. Why are you trying to map the value into a variable if you already have the static final map? Just get the value.

if i am using a map its not working(compile error: Attriubute must be constant), whereas its working if i am using a variable  and placing it in @Value annotation

Rather than trying to purposely work around that, it would be much easier to change your coding style. Use the @Value annotation inside the constructor, retrieve that value and check if it is null or not, if it is, replace it will the map value. prop1Var = (prop1 != null) ? prop1 : map.get("property1")

If you are working with Spring @Value annotation this might be worth a look: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#using-value-with-maps

i want to manipulate default value in annotation only.
i have a properties file from where the value will be fetched for property1, if property1  not present in that file, then i want to use the value from map as default value

Got the solution:
@Value("${test.property:#{T(ConfigValues).configValues['key1']}}")
private String testProperty;
use of charater # and T , can help you get values from other class or map in annotations.
Thank you.

You may put the map in your configuration file so that you can use constant expression in @Value. If you still need further help, I can post the solution as the answer. Thanks.
